# Does anyone know how to correctly put brackets in settings.jsn?

Tags: json, appsettings

I have a problem with visual studio code and json settings. Was trying to adjust settings but it appears as an error. I assume it's because of brackets but tried in various ways and still didnt firgure it out. Just a beginner here, would appreciate any help!
Thanks in advance,

```
{
    "editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true,
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "editorBracketHighlight.foreground1": "#ffd700",
  "editorBracketHighlight.foreground2": "#ff00ff",
  "editorBracketHighlight.foreground3": "#00bfff",
  "editorBracketHighlight.foreground4": "#7cfc00",
  "editorBracketHighlight.unexpectedBracket.foreground": "#ff0000"
   },
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "workbench.startupEditor": "none",
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "liveServer.settings.donotVerifyTags": true,
    "[html]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "[css]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Tokyo Night Storm",
    "editor.wordWrap": "on",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [
        {
            "format": "expanded",
            "extensionName": ".css",
            "savePath": null,
            "savePathReplacementPairs": null
        }
    ],
    "workbench.editor.enablePreview": false,
    "editor.formatOnType": true,
    "prettier.singleQuote": true,
    "prettier.useTabs": true,
    "editor.linkedEditing": true,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"


    "[html]": { 
   "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features" 
},  
"emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
    "html": {
        "inline_break": 2
    }
},


    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
    "prettier.arrowParens": "avoid",
    "prettier.jsxSingleQuote": true,
    "prettier.bracketSameLine": true,
    "prettier.semi": false,
    "prettier.singleQuote": true,
    "prettier.useTabs": true,
    "prettier.printWidth": 120,
    "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
    "editor.wordWrap": "on",
    "breadcrumbs.enabled": false,
    "editor.linkedEditing": true,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "editor.cursorBlinking": "expand",
    "editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true,
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
       "editorBracketHighlight.foreground1": "#ffd700",
       "editorBracketHighlight.foreground2": "#ff00ff",
       "editorBracketHighlight.foreground3": "#00bfff",
       "editorBracketHighlight.foreground4": "#7cfc00",
       "editorBracketHighlight.unexpectedBracket.foreground": "#ff0000"
    },
    "[html]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"
    },
    "emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
        "html": {
            "inline_break": 2
       }
    },
    "emmet.variables": {
       "lang": "pl"
    }

}
```

Not sure why it shows error all the time

Comment: What an error does it show?

Comment: Unable to write into user settings. Please open the user settings to correct errors/warnings in it and try again.

Comment: You've missed a comma `,` after the `"editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"`. Since it is a JSON, you can always use some validation tools like [jsonlint.com](https://jsonlint.com/) to see if it is correct or not.